# Ionic 3 - Error when adding or building iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, cordova, ionic3

I get the following error when building or adding ios with `ionic cordova build ios` or `ionic cordova platform add ios`. The build works fine for Android.

```
IOS project now has deployment target set as: 8.0
IOS project Code Sign Entitlements now set to: App/Resources/App.entitlements
Entitlements file is not in references section, adding it
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/cipriancirstea/Documents/ionic_app/ul_web_hooks/ios/https:/t4edc.app.goo.gl/#apple-app-site-association'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:667:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1326:33)
    at saveContentToFile (/Users/cipriancirstea/Documents/ionic_app/plugins/cordova-universal-links-plugin/hooks/lib/ios/appleAppSiteAssociationFile.js:118:8)
    at /Users/cipriancirstea/Documents/ionic_app/plugins/cordova-universal-links-plugin/hooks/lib/ios/appleAppSiteAssociationFile.js:72:5
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at createNewAssociationFiles (/Users/cipriancirstea/Documents/ionic_app/plugins/cordova-universal-links-plugin/hooks/lib/ios/appleAppSiteAssociationFile.js:70:27)
    at Object.generate (/Users/cipriancirstea/Documents/ionic_app/plugins/cordova-universal-links-plugin/hooks/lib/ios/appleAppSiteAssociationFile.js:45:3)
    at activateUniversalLinksInIos (/Users/cipriancirstea/Documents/ionic_app/plugins/cordova-universal-links-plugin/hooks/afterPrepareHook.js:85:29)
    at /Users/cipriancirstea/Documents/ionic_app/plugins/cordova-universal-links-plugin/hooks/afterPrepareHook.js:50:11
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/Users/cipriancirstea/Documents/ionic_app/ul_web_hooks/ios/https:/t4edc.app.goo.gl/#apple-app-site-association' }
```

config.xml

```
<universal-links>
    <host name="https://t4edc.app.goo.gl/" scheme="https" />
    <host name="example-902cc.firebaseapp.com" scheme="https">
        <path url="/__/auth/callback" />
    </host>
</universal-links>
```

Comment: If you read this: **no such file or directory, open '/Users/cipriancirstea/Documents/ionic_app/ul_web_hooks/ios/https:/t4edc.app.goo.gl/#apple-app-site-association'** You probably import something and it can't find it's dependency.

Answer (score 1):

This is error occurs because you have `https://` prepended to the host `name`.

To get rid of the error, simply replace this:

```
<host name="https://t4edc.app.goo.gl/" scheme="https" />
```

with this:

```
<host name="t4edc.app.goo.gl/" scheme="https" />
```

The reason behind the error is that the plugin automatically creates files under `ul_web_hooks/ios/` and the files are named by the corresponding host name. On MacOs (on *nix platforms in general), colon (`:`) is not allowed to be a part of the file path.

Hope that helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output it looks like you are trying to build on a Windows operating system.

Unfortunately You need an apple or Mac Operating System with Xcode in order to do a proper build for IOS devices.

[For Reference](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/#ios-devices)

Comment: No. I'm building on a Mac. I moved the project from an Ubuntu OS. Why do you say that I'm building from Windows? Can you be more specific? I did run the project on a Windows OS and pushed to the repository. Maybe that affected it somehow.

Comment: @Ciprian It's just that the following path "/Users/cipriancirstea/Documents/" looks like a windows path.  Make sure that the code you pushed to the repository does not include the plugins folder.  Ionic should build that for you based on the operating system.  I would make sure that you aren't pulling in any more files beside the application/src files and the package.json file.

Comment: `node_modules` is not included in the repository. I deleted the folder a bunch of times and reinstalled

Comment: @Ciprian not ideal but if you are still having trouble start a new install/project from scratch.  https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/ Then try to build the project for ios.  Once that is working start to migrate your project over into the new project.

Comment: I thought of doing that, but I might run into the same problem down the line. There is a `<universal-links>` tag in `config.xml` (see my edit) which I'm assuming redirects back to the app after authenticating with Firebase. I use social login through Firebase. So after removing `universal-links-plugin`, it built fine for Android, but when trying to authenticate with any social account doesn't do anything.

Comment: I just removed the plugin and the tag from `config.xml` and it builds the Android app, redirects to Firebase, but once it comes back to the app, it stays on the login page. Someone was saying that implementing lazy loading might help with this redirect issue. Or like you said, just move the whole app to a new project.

Comment: There's nothing indicative about it being a Windows machine.